# Filter by category name in view panel and pager save state behavior

Tags: save, xpages, state, pager

I have the following problem:
I have a XPage that has a combobox whose chosen value restricts the category of view panel through the property 'filter by category name'. The XPage  has a pager save state, however this does not save the state of the restricted view the category chosen in the combobox.

I need to open a document in view panel and act on the document through an agent for example to direct to the view again it remains in the previous state, with for example restricted to the chosen category.

Do this case you will have to ride in the url that the agent is calling the restriction chosen category? There syntax in this regard to XPage?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The value in the combobox should be bound to a sessionScope variable. Then bind the category filter in the view to the sessionScope variable. That will save the chosen category.

Comment: Hi Howard! The combo box is already associated with a variable session scope.

Comment: Then when you navigate to the XPage with the view the variable should be holding your category. Check that with the debug tool bar. And, if your category in the view panel is bound to that session scope var it should work.

Answer (score 0):

When exiting the document are you calling `#{javascript:viewStateBean.restoreState()}` ?

Comment: No, the agent is lotusscript language.